# Select shapefile by their coordinates behaviour

Tags: python, shapefile, numpy, pyshp

I want to filter shapefiles by their latitude behaviour:
If the latitudes of edges **A** and **B** are constantly decreasing or increasing then this class marked as correct, otherwise are incorrect.
For example, the red polygon should be marked as incorrect! (Because it starts increasing at the point **C**.)

[image]

This code works but selects also some correct shapefiles (because I set an absolute value for checking the latitude. This behaviour appears in north and south).

Does someone know how can I detect this kind of shapefile?

**Code**

```
import shapefile
import numpy as np

sf = shapefile.Reader(r"shapefiles/shapefiles.shp")
of = r"_temp/error.txt"

shapes = sf.shapeRecords()
ids = np.zeros(len(shapes))

output = open(of, 'w')
output.close()
output = open(of, 'a')
for shp in shapes:
    lats = np.zeros(len(shp.shape.points))
    lons = np.zeros(len(shp.shape.points))
    for i in range(0, len(shp.shape.points)):
        point = shp.shape.points[i]
        lats[i] = (point[1])
        lons[i] = (point[0])
    if max(lats)>86.5:
        #print shp.record[0]
        continue
    if min(lats)<-79.2:
        #print shp.record[0]
        continue

    # identification of shapefiles crossing dateline - not needed here
    #if max(lons)>179.9: continue
    #if min(lons)<-179.9: continue
    output.write(shp.record[0]+'\n')
output.close()
```

Comment: Couldn't you simply compare 3 consecutive points (moving window) to detect if the delta in x- and y-component is increasing or decreasing? You have to pick the 1st and 2nd point before the `for i in range()` loop and do comparison and assignment of new values in the loop.

Comment: @Detlev If I could detect the edges then your approach is an answer, But do you know how can I detect them?

Comment: You've got a bunch of complications here, including: The first vertex can occur anywhere, the shapefile may be topologically corrupt (not follow right-hand rule), and a loop **can't** always increase or decrease in one dimension. Since every shape has an envelope, you can identify the northeast-most point and use that neighborhood for analysis, but the result will only be correct if the topology is correct.

Comment: Is that code meant to do anything apart from read the data?

Comment: I think if you loop over the points going round the polygon and count the number of times the sign of the difference in latitude between point i and i+1 changes. The polygons you want change sign four times, the ones you don't want change more than that.

Comment: @Vince How could I identify it!? If I could how could I detect the corners or edges afterwards?

Comment: @Spacedman sounds complicated, can you show me exactly what you mean ?

Comment: @Vince you are completely right. MK83: Have the polygon always this banana like shape? Perhaps it is possible to start at the upper right vertex as Vince suggests, compare vertices, and check if the azimuth of the segments changes abrupt. This could mark a *corner*, and so a new *edge*.

Comment: @Spacedman, none of the example successful polygons' latitudes change sign more than twice.

Comment: Although, looking at it again, if all the polygons should only have four sides, then there should only be four total changes of sign in either lat or lon.

Comment: @Tom oops yes twice. you only need the latitude, you can ignore the longitude completely. Probably easier for me to solve this in R...

Comment: @Spacedman, you're absolutely right. However, we still need to find out if the OP really wants to interpret all of his features as having four sides; otherwise, any sign delta threshold is irrelevant.