# How to detect corner of shapefile in python

Tags: python, shapefile

Is there any way to detect corner of each shapefile in python !? (not BBox) 
Or somehow to detect the edges?

[image]

I want to detect each shapefile vertices to calculate the differences in latitude for my program.

I've got some idea for that:

1. Loop over the points going round the polygon and count the number of times the sign of the difference in latitude between point i and i+1 changes.
2. Calculate consecutive three points angle, then pick four sharpest angles

Comment: What would you consider the "corner" of a *circle*? The best you can get is the largest angle subtended by three consecutive vertices.

Comment: @Vince for sure I don not have any circle. how could I find them ?

Comment: Please edit this to be a standalone question. It's okay to reference a different one, but all your tags must be complete, and your problem statement must mention the GIS software in use.

Comment: @Vince sorry, I edited it, can you show me in code how could I find the angles?

Comment: Is there some arbitrary angle threshold you would like to set to define a "corner"?

Comment: @Tom no there is not. I upload some shapefiles which I have.

Comment: Well you have to define "corner" if you want to identify it. By most definitions, every vertex at which the angle changes at all is a corner.

Comment: Should each of your polygons have exactly four "sides"? If so, then you could identify the four sharpest angles.

Comment: you may want to post the shapefile somewhere, in addition to the image you've already shown.  what I'd do is load shape file into python using gdal, convert it as linestring, get the coordinates of each point,  calculate consecutive three points' angle, then pick four sharpest angle like @Tom suggested.  primitive method, there may be better ways

Comment: It's ArcGIS version of answer, but I found this https://geonet.esri.com/thread/45049#post175418 .  Should be able to do similar with other libraries like gdal/ogr.

Comment: Please give an example of your intended final product. Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20253693/1446289?

Comment: @MK83, as soon as we get an answer on whether all the features will have the same number of "sides" by your definition, then we can begin to address your question. If you are not interpreting them all as having the same number of sides (and since you don't want an angle threshold to define a "corner"), then it boils down to a variation on the Justice Stewart conundrum: if you can't define it, we can't code it.

Comment: @Tom All shapefiles have 4 sides. (all have the same number of sides)

Comment: The method for calculating the angle subtended  by three vertices is easily researched. Locating the four largest such angles is just as easy. Neither is particularly GIS-ish, though you should be careful to consider the Cartesian angles subtended in geodetic space (which isn't likely to make a difference in this context).

Comment: By definition, a polygon has *N-1* sides, where *N* is the number of vertices. Your task is to isolate the locations where a *human* brain would deem a "corner", but it means you must learn to think like a machine.

Comment: All above comments are legitimate, but I think after that many instructions MK83 deserved some code to start with, since his intent seems to be quiet obvious for the human brain.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve it in response to requested clarifications rather than creating a comment trail that potential answerers may or may not read. I note that you have not yet taken the [tour] to learn about the focussed Q&A format that we use at GIS SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As many users stated this question has no distinct answer. The results of an analysis may incomplete or fetch the wrong points, dependent on the definition of what should be considered as a corner.

The simplest possibility would be the comparison of angles between adjacent points. As this question is familiar with [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178778/select-shape-file-by-their-coordinates-behavior) I will pick up this code fragment.

```
import shapefile
from math import atan2

# this is the most critical value, and it might be NOT possible to
# find a distinct value for all shapes; in radians
threshold = 0.5

# the input polygons
sf = shapefile.Reader(r'banana.shp')

# for identified corner points
pf = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
pf.field('FID')

shapes = sf.shapeRecords()
for shp in shapes:
    x0, y0 = shp.shape.points[0]
    x1, y1 = shp.shape.points[1]
    az1 = atan2(y1 - y0, x1 - x0)

    for i in range(2, len(shp.shape.points)):
        xi, yi = shp.shape.points[i]
        azi = atan2(yi - y1, xi - x1)

        if abs(azi - az1) > threshold:
            pf.point(x1, y1)
            pf.record(i)

        az1 = azi
        x1, y1 = xi, yi

    xi, yi = shp.shape.points[1]
    azi = atan2(yi - y1, xi - x1)
    if abs(azi - az1) > threshold:
        pf.point(x1, y1)
        pf.record(1)

pf.save('corners')
```

Simple test case with threshold 0.5 radians (-1 < x, y < 1, EPSG: 4326):

[image: test case]

Comment: Interesting, because you stated above that "his intent seems to be quiet [sic] obvious for the human brain", but you and I have very different interpretations of what he meant. Your answer ignores the OP's response to the question: Is there some arbitrary angle threshold you would like to set to define a "corner"? He replied, "no there is not". This answer does not address the OP's clarified intent, as reflected in the comments and in his edited post.